# Flash Builder URL not found

Tags: flash, path, flash-builder, loader

Trying to load a file Flash Builder throws the following error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found.
```

This is how I try to load the file:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("../levels/TeaserI.swf"));
```

If I put the folder "levels" into bin-debug it works fine, but never outside of it. I tried ../../ or leaving out ../ but it makes no difference. Shouldn't Flash Builder put everything that it needs into bin-debug by itself or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Probably not the root cause, but wouldn't a URI schema like http be at good style here? While browsers default to http, I'm actually not sure, to which schema Actionsript / AIR defaults.

Comment: Im not shure, if I understood you. This is a desktop project.

Comment: But even in a desktop project, an URLRequest typically starts with the http: or file: part - the URI schema. Never mind.

Comment: How would that look? This way: loader.load(new URLRequest("file:///../levels/TeaserI.swf")); ?

Comment: Hm, actually, I'm not sure - right now. I probably never used a relative URL with a scheme. My comment was kind of a reflex. Please excuse... http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=url_requests_2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Project->Clean and compile. Does files appears in bin-release (bin-debug) folder? They must appear! If not, check another time Build Path -> Source Path.

Use relative paths and make projector (open swf from standalone player, NOT BROWSER, and make file->make projector). Desktop project cannot run in browser correctly. You need projector or AIR environment.

Move your project into folder on disk root - flash sometimes cannot understand complex paths with spaces and another unusual symbols.

Try use `-use-network=false` compiler option.

And take in consideration: FLEX just an IDE, not runtime environment of your project. If it compiles correctly, it must work. Search errors in your code or folders structure.

Comment: Project clean did the job. Thank you very much! I thought I tested that. Shouldn't this be done automatically?

Comment: I don't know... Sometimes Flex works very freakishly. That's really annoyng thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Flash Builder is not great at understanding folder paths - starting  paths with "/" usually helps. So:

```
loader.load(new URLRequest("/../levels/TeaserI.swf"));
```

Edit, after reading the question properly:

It may also be due to where you are storing your assets. As FB is not putting the assets in bin-debug automatically, it suggests FB is not aware of them.

Either put your assets somewhere within the src folder or add the assets to the project: Project Properties -> Flex Build Path -> Source Path -> Add Folder

Comment: I remember having issues a while ago with Flash Builder not cleaning up the project properly. It didnt load resources and used old versions of them. Can this have somthing to do with it?